# How to set up an acceptor to accept on unix domain and tcp sockets?

Tags: c++, unix, tcp, boost-asio

I am writing a server class, and I would like to be able to support any stream protocol.

This page gives some tips : https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/other_protocols.html

However, it's quite elusive on the acceptor part...

Do you have an example on how to set up an `acceptor` to work with a `boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol::endpoint` (that could be at least ip/TCP or unix domain) ?

Comment: I guess you can just use a `basic_socket_acceptor<generic::stream_protocol>`

Comment: Seems too simple for the documentation not to mention it, so I'm skeptical, but I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have multiple listeners, so e.g.

```
template <typename Socket> struct Listener {
    using Proto    = typename Socket::protocol_type;
    using Acceptor = asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Proto>;
    using Endpoint = Acceptor::endpoint_type;

    Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, Endpoint ep) : acc_(std::move(ex), std::move(ep)) { accept_loop(); }

  private:
    void accept_loop() {
        acc_.async_accept([](error_code ec, Socket s) {
            std::cout << "Accepted (" << ec.message() << ") from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<Session<Socket>>(std::move(s))->Start();
        });
    }
    Acceptor acc_;
};
```

As you can see the session class is also templated on the socket type so you need to implement it only once:

```
template <typename Socket> struct Session /*: BaseSession*/ {
    Session(Socket s) : sock_(std::move(s)) {}

    void Start() {
        read_loop();
    }

  private:
    void read_loop() {
        async_read_until(sock_, asio::dynamic_buffer(message), "\n",
                         [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                             std::cout << "Received (" << ec.message() << "): "              //
                                       << quoted(std::string_view(message).substr(0, n - 1)) //
                                       << std::endl;

                            if (!ec) {
                                message.erase(0, n);
                                read_loop();
                            }
                         });
    }
    std::string message;
    Socket sock_;
};
```

If you need common operations on all session instantiations, consider a base-class.

Now a multi-server is as simple as:

```
struct MultiServer {
    MultiServer(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::set<uint16_t> tcp_listen_ports, std::set<std::string> unix_domain_socket) {
        for (auto p : tcp_listen_ports)
            listeners_.push_back(std::make_shared<Listener<tcp::socket>>(ex, tcp::endpoint{{}, p}));
        for (auto& s : unix_domain_socket)
            listeners_.push_back(std::make_shared<Listener<uxd::socket>>(ex, s));
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void> > listeners_;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    MultiServer      multi(ioc.get_executor(), {8989, 7979}, {"socket1", "socket2"});

    ioc.run_for(10s); // limited for Coliru
}
```

This runs a server listening on 2 tcp ports and 2 unix domain sockets, and spawning the same session on all of them:

[image]

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/910567fd45268206)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;
using uxd = asio::local::stream_protocol;

struct BaseSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<BaseSession> {
    // in case you need any "common" behavior
    // virtual ~BaseSession() = default;
};

template <typename Socket> struct Session : BaseSession {
    Session(Socket s) : sock_(std::move(s)) {}

    void Start() {
        read_loop();
    }

  private:
    void read_loop() {
        async_read_until(sock_, asio::dynamic_buffer(message), "\n",
                         [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                             std::cout << "Received (" << ec.message() << "): "              //
                                       << quoted(std::string_view(message).substr(0, n - 1)) //
                                       << std::endl;

                            if (!ec) {
                                message.erase(0, n);
                                read_loop();
                            }
                         });
    }
    std::string message;
    Socket sock_;
};

template <typename Socket> struct Listener {
    using Proto    = typename Socket::protocol_type;
    using Acceptor = asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Proto>;
    using Endpoint = Acceptor::endpoint_type;

    Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, Endpoint ep) : acc_(std::move(ex), std::move(ep)) { accept_loop(); }

  private:
    void accept_loop() {
        acc_.async_accept([](error_code ec, Socket s) {
            std::cout << "Accepted (" << ec.message() << ") from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<Session<Socket>>(std::move(s))->Start();
        });
    }
    Acceptor acc_;
};

struct MultiServer {
    MultiServer(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::set<uint16_t> tcp_listen_ports, std::set<std::string> unix_domain_socket) {
        for (auto p : tcp_listen_ports)
            listeners_.push_back(std::make_shared<Listener<tcp::socket>>(ex, tcp::endpoint{{}, p}));
        for (auto& s : unix_domain_socket)
            listeners_.push_back(std::make_shared<Listener<uxd::socket>>(ex, s));
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void> > listeners_;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    MultiServer      multi(ioc.get_executor(), {8989, 7979}, {"socket1", "socket2"});

    ioc.run_for(10s); // limited for Coliru
}
```